# Array data wont display in a table

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table

I have an ajax function which sends a get request to an api and returns data in the following format-

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "doej@gmail.com",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "maths"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "chemistry"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I need to display this data in a table but am having trouble getting the subjects array to display correctly, ie as a list in one table cell. I have tried to put the array data into another table inside the main one but it's not working out. I presume I'm going very wrong somewhere in my iteration loops.

```
function getPeople() {


     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://example.com",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {



             // fill a table with the JSON
           $("table.mytable").html("<tr><th></th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Subjects</th></tr>"  );

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].subjects.length; j++) {

          var subjects = data[i].subjects[j];
        $("table.insidetable").append('<tr><td>' + subjects + 'tr><td>')
      }

    $("table.mytable").append('<tr><td><input type = "checkbox" id = '+data[i].id+'>'  + "</td><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + "table.insidetable"  + "</td></tr>");
}

         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
   }
```

Comment: do you have any error in your js console?

Comment: I think you need to parse the json data first using JSON.parse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working (tested) code.

```
var data = [{
  "firstname": "John",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "email": "doej@gmail.com",
  "subjects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
    "name": "maths"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "chemistry"
    }
        ]
},
{
  "firstname": "Steve",
  "lastname": "Gentile",
  "email": "steve@gmail.com",
  "subjects": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "history"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
    "name": "geography"
    }
  ]
}];

$("table.mytable").html("<tr><th></th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Subjects</th></tr>");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var subjectList = '';

    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].subjects.length; j++) {
      subjectList += '<li>' + data[i].subjects[j].name + '</li>';
    }

    $("table.mytable").append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id=' + i +'/></td><td>' + data[i].firstname + '</td><td>' + data[i].lastname + '</td><td><ul>' + subjectList  + '</ul></td></tr>');
}
```

It seems there are many problems in below statement like,

- Tags are not closed properly
- Properties that do not exist are being used (data[i].id)
- Single and Double quotes don't match

...

```
$("table.mytable").append('<tr><td><input type = "checkbox" id = '+data[i].id+'>'  + "</td><td>" +data[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + "table.insidetable"+ "</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guess are you missing a `'<'`?

In the line:

```
 $("table.insidetable").append('<tr><td>' + subjects + 'tr><td>')
```

Also

```
$("table.mytable").append('<tr><td><input type = "checkbox" id = '+data[i].id+'>'  + "</td><td>" + data[i].firstname + "</td><td>" + data[i].lastname + "</td><td>" + "table.insidetable"  + "</td></tr>");
```

I don't think you should be appending "table.insidetable"? This will be seen rendered as the value "table.insidetable" and not the contents of the table. I *think* this should rather be something like `$("table.insidetable").val()`

Comment: Spotted something else and updated my answer, hopefully that helps!